# Stack Exchange newsletter arriving in spam folder

Tags: support, newsletter, spam-detection

I have subscribed to a few Stack Exchange newsletters quite a while ago. In the last few weeks, all of these emails are ending up in my spam folder.

> [image: Gmail account screenshot]

I have checked my spam rules, and there is nothing regarding Stack Exchange (in a fact, I have no custom spam rules).

There is only one thing I see as a potential issue -- I am registered with a different email here on Stack Exchange and all my emails are redirected to a Gmail account. But it worked fine for almost a year.

Just a note -- the email that I receive is the correct one, all links are ending on Stack sites. Also, I have tried to mark these emails as "Not spam" several times, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this **is not the actual newsletter**!!!

Do not open this, it is most likely some scam.

The "via seznam.cz" means it was not sent from Stack Exchange. They do not use any third party service to send emails, they send it using their own signed email server:

> [image]

Comment: It is actual newsletter. Seznam.cz is local e-mail provider in my country and it is correctly redirecting all my e-mails (from e-mail adrress I have there and my SE account is registered on this e-mail). But it seems, they are signing the redirected e-mails as send from seznam.cz - that's odd.

Comment: So that's the reason it's marked as spam, Google are correct. They can't possibly know it's legit. For all Google know, they can change the email while "redirecting", adding spam links, etc.

Comment: Jup, that makes sense. Gonna to change my e-mail to gmail one, this should solve it. Thank you for help!